# How to make use of jsessionid together with basic authentication

Tags: session-cookies, basic-authentication

I am using JBoss 7.1 and have secured my web application with Basic authentication but I want only the first call to require the Basic authentication header, sequent calls should use the jsessionid for authentication. How to accomplish this?

So far I have created a rest servlet enforcing the creation of a session with a call to request.getSession()

```
@Path("/rest/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET()
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String sayHello(@Context HttpServletResponse response,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        return "Hello World! " + request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    }
```

My idea was that any other calls should only require the jsessionid cookie, but when looking in fiddler I see that the first call is behaving as expected. First you get a 401 and the client is re-sending including the basic authorization header and a jsessionid is returned. On the second call the jsessionid cookie is included but I still get an 401 that triggers the client to re-send the Basic authorization header.

This is the returned headers from the successful authenticated first call.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: No-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AFDFl2etiUNkn-mpM+DXr3KE; Path=/Test
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 18
Date: Tue, 29 Jan 2013 09:12:48 GMT

Hello World! test1
```

when I make a second call the jsessionid is included

```
GET /Test/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: cwl-rickard:8080
Cookie: JSESSIONID=AFDFl2etiUNkn-mpM+DXr3KE
```

and I am getting a 401 enforcing the client to re-send the request including the basic authorization header.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: No-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="ApplicationRealm"
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 958
Date: Tue, 29 Jan 2013 09:12:48 GMT
```

Any ideas what I am missing.